# printing multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array ($SESSION) and after writing in it (with the function ajout_liste) I want to print it (with the function affiche_liste). My problem is even I write in it $SESSION is always empty.
Any idea?

```
 <?php
    
    class liste_livre{
        public $SESSION = array('Titre' => array(),
                                'Auteur' => array(),
                                'Editeur' => array(),
                                'Annee' => array(),
                                );
        // create a formulary
        public function notre_formulaire() {
    
            $str = '<form action="" method="POST">';
            $str .= 'Que voulez vous faire ?<br>';
            $str .= 'Ajouter un livre<br>';
            $str .= '<input type="radio" name="radio" value="ajoute"><br>';
            $str .= '<input type="text" name="titre" placeholder="Titre">';
            $str .= '<input type="text" name="auteur" placeholder="Auteur">';
            $str .= '<input type="text" name="editeur" placeholder="Editeur">';
            $str .= '<input type="text" name="annee" placeholder="Annee">';
            $str .= '<br>';
            $str .= 'Afficher la liste des livres<br>';
            $str .= '<input type="radio" name="radio" value = "affiche"><br>';
            $str .= '<p>';
            $str .= '<input type="Submit" name="submit" value = "Valider">';
            $str .= '</form>';
    
            return $str;
        }
    
        public function form_liste(){
            //ADD ERROR IF EMPTY !!!!!!!!!!!!!
            $titre = $auteur = $editeur = $annee = "";
    
            // print the formulary
            echo $this-> notre_formulaire();
    
            // the choice
            if (isset($_POST['radio'])) {
                // On recupere son choix dans la variable $choix
                $choix = $_POST['radio'];
                // Si cette variable est egale à ajout, c'est a dire si la personne veut ajouter un nouveau livre
                if( $choix == 'ajoute' ){
                    echo $this->ajout_liste($_POST["titre"],$_POST["auteur"],$_POST["editeur"],$_POST["annee"]);
                }
                // Si la personne veut juste afficher les livres 
                else if ( $choix == 'affiche' ){
                    $this->affiche_list();
                }
            }
        }
        //add a book
        public function ajout_liste($titre,$auteur,$editeur,$annee){
            $this ->SESSION['Titre'] = $titre;
            $this ->SESSION['Auteur'] = $auteur;
            $this ->SESSION['Editeur'] = $editeur;
            $this ->SESSION['Annee'] = $annee;
            echo $titre;
            echo $auteur;
            echo $editeur;
            echo $annee;
        }
    
        // print the list
        public function affiche_list(){
    
            $nb = count($this->SESSION['Titre']);
            if ($nb != 0){
                foreach ($this -> SESSION as $masterkey => $mastervalue) {
                
                    for($x = 0; $x <= $nb; $x++){
                        echo "<p>".$masterkey." ".$mastervalue[$x]."<br>";
                    }
    
                }
            }
            else{
                echo "Il n'y a pas de livre ! Veuillez en enregistrer pour pouvoir les afficher ";
                }
    
             }
            /*
            echo $this ->SESSION['Titre'];
            echo $this ->SESSION['Auteur'];
            echo $this ->SESSION['Editeur']; 
            echo $this ->SESSION['Annee']; */
    
        }
    }       
    ?>
```

EDIT:
I call all my functions thanks to index.php file:

```
<?php
@ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

require_once('page.php');
require_once('liste_livre.php');

$form = new liste_livre();
$pag = new Page();


echo $pag->entete('premiere page');
$form -> form_liste();
echo $pag->piedPage();

?>
```

here is what I got when I add a book:

[image]

And when I want to print the book list (even after I add one: harry potter in this case) I have this which mean it's empty:

[image]

EDIT2: here is the code for Page class

```
<?php

class Page {

    private $titre;

    public function entete($title)
    {
        $this->titre = $title;
        return '<!doctype html>
        <html lang="fr">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>'.$this->titre.'</title>
            <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  fichier a creer -->
            <!--<script src="script.js"></script>  fichier a creer -->
        </head>
        <body>';
    }

    public function piedPage()
    {
        return '</body></html>';
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: how do you call the ajout_liste, and why you say the $SESSION is always empty.  can you show them here?

Comment: Where is the code for the Page class?

Comment: i have just edit the code for the Page class , thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the session before you can use it.

You could use [`session_start`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php):

```
<?php
@ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
session_start(); // <-- start the session and make $_SESSION available

require_once('page.php');
require_once('liste_livre.php');

$form = new liste_livre();
$pag = new Page();


echo $pag->entete('premiere page');
$form -> form_liste();
echo $pag->piedPage();
```

Or you could enable [`session.auto_start`](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) in your php.ini file, but this will affect all php files on your server and may break systems which rely on starting their own sessions.

```
[PHP]
session.auto_start = 1
```

If you actually want to use a global variable called `$SESSION` you'll need to make it available whenever you use it.

```
<?php
@ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

global $SESSION; // <-- make $SESSION a global

require_once('page.php');
require_once('liste_livre.php');

$form = new liste_livre();
$pag = new Page();

echo $pag->entete('premiere page');
$form -> form_liste();
echo $pag->piedPage();
```

Then also get the global `$SESSION` in `liste_livre`:

```
<?php
global $SESSION; // <-- tell PHP to use global $SESSION and not a class specific version

class liste_livre{
    // This won't use the global $SESSION and will instead use $this->SESSION;
    public $SESSION = array('Titre' => array(),
                            'Auteur' => array(),
                            'Editeur' => array(),
                            'Annee' => array(),
                            ); 

    // create a formulary
    public function notre_formulaire() {
        global $SESSION; // <-- global $SESSION

        // Get something from global session
        $SESSION['something'];

        // Get something from class session
        $this->SESSION['Titre'];
...
```

If you want to use the `$form` session in `$page` you can do that also, but you'll need to either make `$form` global or call it inside `Page`:

```
<?php
require_once('liste_livre.php');

class Page {

    private $titre;

    public function entete($title)
    {
        $form = new liste_livre();

        $this->titre = $form->SESSION['Titre'];
        return '<!doctype html>
        <html lang="fr">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>'.$this->titre.'</title>
            <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  fichier a creer -->
            <!--<script src="script.js"></script>  fichier a creer -->
        </head>
        <body>';
    }

    public function piedPage()
    {
        return '</body></html>';
    }

}
```

Global example

```
<?php
@ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

require_once('page.php');
require_once('liste_livre.php');

global $form; // <-- make $form global

$form = new liste_livre();
$pag = new Page();


echo $pag->entete('premiere page');
$form -> form_liste();
echo $pag->piedPage();
```

Use `$form` in `Page`

```
<?php

class Page {

    private $titre;

    public function entete($title)
    {
        global $form; // <-- use global $form

        $this->titre = $form->SESSION['Titre'];
        return '<!doctype html>
        <html lang="fr">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>'.$this->titre.'</title>
            <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">  fichier a creer -->
            <!--<script src="script.js"></script>  fichier a creer -->
        </head>
        <body>';
    }

    public function piedPage()
    {
        return '</body></html>';
    }

}
```